# Laravel - Unauthenticated redirect issue with multiple authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

I have a multiple authentication system set up in Laravel 5.7

There is an 'admin' section of the site and a 'learner' section of the site.
When you try to access a portion of either site, it redirects you the correct login page if you're not logged in yet.

However, if follow these steps, I come across an issue with the redirects:

1. I try to access a portion (not the login) of the 'admin' site, which redirects me to the admin login.
2. Then if I link DIRECTLY to the login section of the 'learner' page
   and log in, instead of going to the home page it will redirect me
   back to the admin login.

It properly logs me in, but improperly redirects to the other login page.
The issue also happens vice versa, if I get an automatic redirect to the 'learner' then link directly to the admin login page and log in.

I believe I've narrowed the issue down to the unaunthenticated function I've placed in the Exception/Handler.php file, but I can't figure out where to go from there.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'learner':
                $login = 'learner.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

Using each separate login page works fine. It's just when you follow the process above that I  see issues.

I use separate middleware in each controller like this:

Admin Home Controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Admin login controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```

Learner home controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:learner');

    }
```

Learner login Controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:learner')->except('logout');
    }
```

Solution: Clearing out the intended url with Session:forget('url.intended');

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // dd($exception);
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'learner':
                $login = 'learner.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        Session::forget('url.intented'); 
        return redirect()->route($login);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using separate Middlewares to protect the routes or are you using the same middleware?

Comment: I am using separate middleware in each controller via a __construct.
I will update my main post with what they look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: Clearing out the intended url with Session:forget('url.intended');

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // dd($exception);
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'learner':
                $login = 'learner.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        Session::forget('url.intented'); 
        return redirect()->route($login);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I use in production for an application that has two user classes which both must be logged into access their separate resources. The User class uses the default Laravel Authentication with no changes, however, my Admin class users use this custom middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Admin;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return redirect(route('admin.login'));
        }

        if (!$request->user() instanceof Admin) {
            return redirect(route('restricted'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I registered the AdminMiddleware in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` like so:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,

    /*** OTHER MIDDLEWARES ARE HERE ***/
];
```

In the `routes/web.php` file I have wrapped the routes like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    /**** ADMIN ROUTES ARE HERE ****/
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    /**** CLIENT ROUTES ARE HERE ****/
});
```

And I have a custom AdminLoginController which overwrites a the `$redirect` path variable as well as the `guard()`,  `showLoginForm()` and `redirectTo()` functions and looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    } 

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin.login');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        return route('admin.home');
    }

}
```

Finally in the `config/auth.php` I have the following references to guards, providers and passwords:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ], 

],

'passwords' => [
    'admin' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Of course this means that my Admins and Users are stored on separate tables in the database, but it works really well without any issues so I'm perfectly okay with that.

Comment: Where/how did you register the AdminMiddleware? I can't seem to get mine to work properly.

Comment: Sorry I missed that before, I just added it as the second code block

Comment: Thanks. So where do you actually call middleware('admin)?
It looks like the only middleware you're using for the admin routes is auth:admin

Comment: Your correct I am only referencing `auth:admin` in the route file, but you can also call it in the a Controller __construct method as well.

Comment: In the meantime, I found a solution of my own!

Adding this to the end of the handler function clears out the indended routes and stops it from redirecting improperly.

Session::forget('url.intented'); 
return redirect()->route($login);